# return redux form values to state with handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a reduxForm which uses a formValueSelector to gather form values. I want to push those values into the empty state to use with a method.

```
state = {
 employmentHistory: [],
 }

 handleChange = (formValues) => {
 const { employmentHistory } = this.state;
 employmentHistory.push(formValues);

    this.setState({
      employmentHistory,
    }, () => {
     if (employmentHistory.length > 0) {
    this.props.whenUserCompletedQuestion({
      employmentHistory,
    });
  } else {
    this.props.whenUserCompletedQuestion({
      employmentHistory: null,
    });
  }
});
console.log(employmentHistory);
}
```

This is the form:

```
 <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <FieldArray
    name="employmentHistory"
    component={someComponent}
    roles={translatedTypes(roles, 'vehicleTypes')}
    dispatch={more.dispatch}
    driverProfile={driverProfile}
    change={more.change}
    profileReminder
   />
  </form>
```

This is the redux connect:

```
 const selector = formValueSelector('employmentHistory');

 export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    initialValues: {
     employmentHistory: state.driver.employmentHistory,
      ...pickInitialValues(state.driver.driverProfile),
    },
    formValues: getFormValues('employmentHistory')(state),
  })
 )(reduxForm({
  form: 'employmentHistory'})()
```

Comment: This is what is console.logged   Array [ Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy ]
0 : Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
length : 6

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Sorry was half a sleep when posted. The question is, why cant I push these values from form into this employmentHistory state so that I can trigger another function with the values in the state.